# How to check if Label contains part of string

Tags: c#, label, substring

I'm trying to check if my label is containing just part from a string. Let's say in my Label.Text i have " Food : 100 " from here i want to check if it contains Food and after this use substring to cut the first 7 digits (including the blank spaces) and just get the number 100 how can i do this ? Is this the right approach ? Any help is appreciated

I tried to do it with linq but it wont works since it's label

```
 if (status.Text.Any(x => x.Contains("Food")))
 {
         //do somne work       
 }
```

Comment: `Is this the right approach ?` You didn't even show what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an option how to solve this problem. But instead of using `Substring()` I used `Remove()`.

```
var labelText = Label.Text;
var foodValue = "";

if(labelText.Contains("Food"))
   foodValue = labelText.Remove(0,7);
```

After that code executed, you can find the value 100 in `foodValue`.

Comment: Point me if I'm wrong but .Contains() is checking if the entire string=="Food" not just part of it

Comment: Contains, searches the whole string to find a matching "food" substring. So whats your point dB.Employee ? equal to is very different from Contains. It's just English, this tea contains sugar...

Comment: @dB.Employee No just part of it. This matches too: "FoodProductionSite".

Comment: @dB.Employee [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find the documentation about the `String.Contains()` method

Comment: Sorry my mistake didn't even tried using .Contains last time i used it on strings and it didn't check just for parts of it instead checked if the entire string==something

Comment: @dB.Employee Is it possible that you mean `String.Compare()` ? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the msdn documentation about it. `String.Compare()` compares two whole strings.

Answer (score 0):

Could also use Regex

```
var labelText = Label.Text;
var foodValue = string.Empty;
var regx = new Regex(@"^Food\s*:\s*(\d*)\s*$");

var result = regx.Match(labelText);
if (result.Success)
{
    foodValue = result.Groups[1].Value;
}
```